# Jointly complete and sufficient statistics for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family, complete-statistics

Consider the random sample X from the multivariate normal distribution where xi are i.i.d as N(µ,Σ).
*Show that the sample mean x̄ and Sample covariance matrix S are jointly complete and sufficient statistics for µ and Σ

In my attempt I tried to justify that it belongs to the exponential family but I still don't know how to trigger out the sample mean x̄ and Sample covariance matrix S
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Secondly, it can been shown that X is distributed according to a full rank exponential family with minimal sufficient statistics T(X)=(x̄,S). In an exponential family, it turns out that not only is the statistic minimal sufficient but it is also complete.

Therefore x̄ and S are jointly complete and sufficient statistics for µ and Σ